# Android Studio Google Maps cannot get latlng or find the blue dot

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to use Google Maps on my app. So far I am able to load the map onto a SupportMapFragment which is called onto my MainActivity as a fragment. However, I am unable to see a blue dot despite enabling locations. I am not able to get the latitude or longitude to show up in the logs as well. Can someone help me with this? I am quite lost. Could it be the permissions I have set? I have also added the necessary permissions in the manifest. 
This is my code

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements LocationListener,OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    Location location;
    Marker locationMarker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleAPIClient(){
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        Double latitude = currentLocation.latitude;
        Double longitude = currentLocation.longitude;
        this.location = location;
        if(locationMarker!=null){
            locationMarker.remove();
        }
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(currentLocation);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
        locationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        if(googleApiClient!=null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                buildGoogleAPIClient();
                this.googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }else{
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }else{
            buildGoogleAPIClient();
            this.googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(googleApiClient!=null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,locationRequest,this);
        }
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //Ask for permission again once the user sees the explanation
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Location Permission required")
                        .setMessage("This app requires location permissions in order to function")
                        .setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }else{
                //No explanation required. Just request for permissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(googleApiClient==null){
                        buildGoogleAPIClient();
                    }
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        this.googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you are showing you are never calling `getMapAsync` on your `SupportMapFragment` so basically you are just showing a map.

Add `getMapAsync` to your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Comment: Hi I've added it but there is still no marker. It did ask for permission though.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the following permissions too:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: That has been added. Thanks for the reply!